# How to create a toolbar for a whole domain

Tags: jquery, html, toolbar

I have 10 systems hosted in the same domain let's call it (domain.com). I want to create a toolbar that will float on top of all them and will link them to each other and to a main company page.

My question is, what's the best way to accomplish this? i was think about using an iframe, but the toolbar has dropdown menus that cut when i use an iframe.

I'm thinking there has to be a good and fast way to do this... any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What i did to solve this was this:
I created a separated system only for the toolbar and then i added a curl request on system to load the toolbar if user was registered. This worked, i'm not sure it it's the best approach, but it was good enough for me.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this article and see if any of the already existing services work for you:

- [5 social toolbars for your blog to keep visitors engaged](http://www.webdeveloperjuice.com/2010/11/29/5-social-toolbars-for-your-blog-to-keep-visitors-engaged/)

If not, try creating your own. Here's a good starting point:

- [jQuery Fubar – How To Create A Website Toolbar From Scratch And Add Widgets To It](http://addyosmani.com/blog/jquery-fubar-how-to-create-a-website-toolbar-from-scratch-and-add-widgets-to-it/)

Comment: that's okay... but i need to create one toolbar for all sites... so, i need to create the toolbar just once... and then load it dynamically on all systems...

Comment: You can create your own toolbar, keep everything you need in one page, host it in one server, and then use jQuery to load the toolbar via AJAX in every one of your sites.

Comment: do you know of any working samples? i was trying to do that but i had some issues...